# Will my Heroku app working on 1 web dyno stay active if I pay for 1 worker dyno?

Tags: heroku

I currently have an app deployed on Heroku which runs on two web dynos so it won't go to sleep if it remains inactive for a certain time.

Now if I scale it down to only one web dyno (free) and instead pay for one worker dyno, will Heroku always keep my app active?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will still idle - you *NEED* to have more than a single web dyno

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-idling

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the New Relic add-on to monitor your app and keep it alive. There is a tab in settings to configure availability monitoring.

Comment: This sounds pretty great. :) Will it keep my app alive even if it's a node.js app (that's currently not supported from what I gather)? Will it keep my app from ideling even if I just add the add-on and don't configure it properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid a single web dyno from idling by using a monitoring service like pingdom.com since it's periodically sending a request to your web dyno.

Answer (score 1):

Try Pingdom. Free plans include one website check. I use this service to keep my app active all the time.

> Pingdom tests your websites and other infrastructure components as
>   often as every minute to make sure it is all up and running.

From [Pingdom Homepage](https://www.pingdom.com/)

Pingdom does this by "pinging" or rather requesting a resource from your website on a regular interval. This has the side effect of keeping your website "active", cache's primed, etc.. because your website is seeing regular "traffic" (the requests coming from pingdom).

Comment: I'm not sure if they still offer this free plan for 1 website

Answer (score 0):

Try Un-idler. You don't need to sign in and it's free.
http://unidler.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/ it will ping your app every 30 minutes so your app won't go to sleep.

Comment: Looks like the website is idle itself(not working anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Try [CloudUp](http://www.thecloudup.com). It visits your apps periodically to keep them awake. It is free, and you can add as many apps as you want. It also activates apps on Google App Engine and Azure.